# How to root my android device without losing data?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 4.4-kitkat, backup, stock-android

I want to root my android device but I have a lot of personal data stored in it. It also doesn't have a micro sd card slot. So I was wondering if there is any way to root my device without losing any data and without using a PC?

Comment: Can you connect your phone to PC and backup the personal datas

Comment: Sameer brother i don't have my PC. I've mentioned it now

Answer (score 2):

You can! You just need to backup your data! Which phone are using? Brand? Sony devices have a app called "backup and restore", by backing up your data you can get back your data in case if you lose it! I think there is a way not losing data while rooting your phone.

Comment: I have Motorola Moto G

Comment: @Sarthak go to settings -> backup and restore then backup your data..

Comment: that's alright but i have big files also which takes too much time to download and my data/progress is saved in them. Will these files and the data/progress saved in these files will also be backed up?

Comment: @Sarthak it will show you which data you want to backup,  if you want back up internal storage or all the app data + contacts everything..

Comment: It's just showing 3 things namely backup my data, backup account and automatically restore

Comment: @Sarthak backup your data

Comment: Already done that, but beneath that option it's written 'backup app data, Wi-Fi password and Google server settings'

Comment: @Sarthak  yeah!!  It means your backup data has been done and Wi-Fi password and settings are also backed!!

Comment: Last query, the files I was talking about are PSP Games that I play on my device. Now I'm not sure will the data of the PSP games will also be backed up?

Comment: @Sarthak ya! It will backup your whole internal storage, btw which emulator are you using?  PPSSPP??  I'm using PPSSPP!

Comment: ,Yeah me too!PPSSPP it's the best

Comment: @Sarthak yeah !!!

Comment: Thanks brother, you saved me. BTW when I was rooting my Samsung Galaxy S4 then I used Odin through which also no data loss was there. Isn't there any way to use Odin on Moto G

Comment: @Sarthak sorry brother no idea

Comment: @syed_sami the way you describe does not cover everything, but only backup parts. I know of no manufacturer including a backup app really doing a full backup (which can only be done by root-apps, or via ADB). See our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for details, and follow its links for more details.

Comment: @Izzy i was just trying to keep it simple

Comment: I understand. But this way it doesn't fully comply with "without losing data": things are not covered by a backup cannot be restored after a wipe, and hence are lost. Will mostly affect app data, game levels, and the like (which would e.g. be covered by *Helium Backup* or `adb backup`, see [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575). Unfortunately, without root bein already in place, both require a PC, which Sarthak doesn't have at disposal currently.